# Search child element in ET

Tags: python, elementtree

I'm trying to search an XML file. I need to

- check if the 'localteam' name matches my query (e.g 'Team A')
- If a match is found check the 'awayteam' name matches my second condition (e.g 'Team B'), the elemt of which is below the 'localteam' within the same element
- If 'awayteam' matches my query get the id of the parent (in 'match') and exit the search.

I can get to the localteam element but I'm not sure how to then search for the awayteam and also go 'up' a level to get the id... I've tried using child.iter() and child.find('awayteam'), but neither has worked..

Thus far I have..

```
for child in root.iter('localteam'):
    gs_name = child.get('name')
    if gs_name == 'Team A':
        print child.tag, child.attrib
        for step_child in child.iter():
            print step_child.tag, step_child.attrib
            gs_name = child.get('name')
```

XML

```
<scores sport="sports">
  <category name="NAME" id="1419" file_group="USA">
      <match date="21.07.2013" time="04:00" status="Finished" id="56456456">
         <localteam name="Team A" />
         <random name="yyy" />
         <awayteam name="Team B" />
         <random name="xxx" />
</match>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for `match` elements instead:

```
for match in root.iter("match"):
    if (match.find("localteam").get("name") == "Team A" and
        match.find("awayteam").get("name") == "Team B"):
        print match.get("id")
        break
```

The above will raise AttributeErrors if the `find` calls don't find anything, so you may want to add some additional checks or error handling; e.g.

```
for match in root.iter("match"):
    localteam = match.find("localteam")
    awayteam = match.find("awayteam")
    if localteam is not None and awayteam is not None and ...
```